# PHP how to create the same hash from the same string?

Tags: php, hash, md5

Have not found exact answer. I want to get browser fingerprints and then create hash from fingerprints and record in mysql. So when user logins next time, i compare the mysql hash with hash of particular login and if hashes are not the same, decided to send email to user.

Question is how to create the same hash from the same string?

Tried `md5`

```
$string = 'I could use a users IP address as the fingerprint, however, there could be multiple other users on the same IP. This is how passwords are typically stored (using this or another hash function, typically with a salt method added.) Checking a password is then done by hashing the input and comparing to the stored hash.';

echo md5($string).  "\n";
echo md5($string).  "\n";
echo md5($string).  "\n";
```

Example is here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8bd6dfc7a1ba69edb6e175c9a2c04d9a3704228b

As i see all hashes are the same (tried on 2 different browsers, so time is also different and hashes are the same). So can i be 100% sure that `md5` creates the same hash from the same string?

Comment: Yes, `md5()` will always give you the same output if the input doesn't change

Comment: Yes, `md5` hash is always the same. However, there are collisions; e.g. two different strings can produce the same hash.

Comment: Thanks for comments

Comment: Yes, `md5` is expected to generate the same hash from an identical string, unless it is used in combination with a salt. `md5` will however generate [duplicate hashes from different strings](https://3v4l.org/Fu9ev) as well.

Comment: You might search on how other sites validate users.  Many seem to use a combination of a persistent cookie then as a second factor they send a validation code using one of (email, phone call, text message)  When the persistent cookie disappears they require the second factor again for the next login.  One reason to do this is the browsers are looking at making fingerprinting more difficult for privacy reasons.

Comment: I recommend specifically looking into [JWT authentication](https://jwt.io/introduction/), which I utilize for 2FA device tokens, so the user password is not a consideration in the token validation, and you can mass invalidate the JWT tokens issued.

Comment: Browser fingerprinting is done using javascript. Is that what you are trying to get - a browser fingerprint?

Comment: @RamRaider Not only browser fingerprints. As i understand if user resizes browser, then all changes. I also want to get operating system etc. But the question is what to store in mysql (not to store long text with all fingerprints). Seems MD5 is suitable. I mean, user enters password, i check if fingerprints the same. If not, then send warning (something similar as gmail does).

Comment: it is possible to get collisions with MD5 hashes (ie: two different strings producing the same hash ) - rare but possible. A `browser fingerprint` should not change simply if the user resizes his/her screen. Any information supplied by the client ( such as OS ) is suspect and can be manipulated

Comment: @RamRaider I will think what to do. I just want some solution: if someone "steals" user login details and then logins from own computer. I send warning email to user (so that user is aware, that from another device someone logged in) or may be email with confirmation link. Not sure that "thief" will provide me all possible fingerprints. I plan to do something similar as Gmail (if i login from unknown device, Gmail sends me email)

Comment: The `fingerprinting` method I use generates a 10digit number as fingerprint based upon all manner of properties of window,screen,navigator and such like. That integer is stored against logins. This seems to work OK but every time Chrome updates ( or other browser ) the fingerprint will change too.

Comment: any information sent from the client can be spoofed, IP, browser client, etc. Effectively never trust anything sent from the client. As Google/JWT works, generating a signed token from your server, that is unique per device, and only contains a user id to match against, that is stored on the client and the validation/private key in the database. It is a multitude more difficult to spoof or steal, since it is signed. It can be revoked at-will, invalidating authentication with a single or all issued tokens. Additionally avoiding an alert when the browser/OS version changes from a minor update.